# Can't figure out how to take data from form in Java EE Spring Web Project

Tags: java, spring, web-applications

I feel like a complete idiot, for the last 5 hours at work I'm trying to figure out Spring and how to do this.

I have a form inside "checklist.jsp" and I want to take the data that the user puts into the form. I will use that data later, but I just want to capture it now...

I have checklist.jsp which has a controller called "ChecklistController.java".
Here is my form in checklist.jsp

```
<form method="POST" action="checklist.jsp">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>FQDN:</td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type='text' id="FQDN" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" id="rdoScript" /></td>
        <td>Script 1 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" id="rdoScript" /></td>
        <td>Script 2</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Run" id="selectionSubmit" />
 </form>
```

Please note: I was using  tags but I changed it so I could actually see the page. I've been playing with it back and forth.

This is my ChecklistController.java

```
@Controller
// handling methods are relative to this controller
public class ChecklistController {
    private ChecklistService service;
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ChecklistController.class);

    @RequestMapping("/checklist")
    public ModelAndView checklist() throws Exception{
        ModelAndView mavChecklist = new ModelAndView("checklist");
        mavChecklist.addObject("test",service.simpleTest());
        mavChecklist.addObject("date",service.getDateTime());
        return mavChecklist;
    }


    @Autowired
    public void setService(ChecklistService service){
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

My idea was to get the data into a bean, so I made this class. UserSel.java

```
public class UserSel implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String script;
    private String FQDN;

    public UserSel(){
    }

    public String getFQDN() {
        return FQDN;
    }

    public void setFQDN(String fqdn) {
        FQDN = fqdn;
    }

    public String getScript() {
        return script;
    }

    public void setScript(String script) {
        this.script = script;
    }
}
```

I hope I provided enough information.
I want to take the FQDN and the Script selection and be able to use those selections from the user (to run remote scripts).

Please let me know if additional information is required -- I'm frustrated with Spring at the moment :(

EDIT: 
Adding current ChecklistController.java

```
@Controller
// handling methods are relative to this controller
public class ChecklistController {
private ChecklistService service;
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ChecklistController.class);


@RequestMapping("/checklist")
public ModelAndView checklist(@ModelAttribute(value="UserSel")UserSel userSel) throws Exception{
    ModelAndView mav = viewRender();
    String FQDN = userSel.getFQDN();
    String getScript = userSel.getScript();
    mav.addObject("FQDN", FQDN);
    mav.addObject("script",getScript);
    return mav; 
}

@RequestMapping("/newchecklist")
public ModelAndView viewRender() {
    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("UserSel ", new UserSel ());
    mav.setViewName("checklist");
    return mav;
}

@Autowired
public void setService(ChecklistService service){
    this.service = service;
}
}
```

Comment: I think you mean spring, not swing.

Comment: I didn't know someone can else can submit an edit for me to approve or reject. That is handy!

Comment: What do you mean, "so you can see the page"? Are you using a browser without a "view source"?

Comment: Also, it's not you specifically that needs to approve/reject edits, anyone with enough rep can.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what the problem is. Is it just a matter of it not getting into the controller?

Comment: Correct. That is the issue, I can't get it into the controller. Sorry for the lack of info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) add spring's form tld. and rewrite your form like this

```
<form:form commandName="UserInfo" method="POST" action="/web/checklist">
  <tr>
        <td>FQDN:</td>
        <td colspan="2"><input path="FQDN" /></td>
        <td><form:radiobutton path="script" value="1"/></td>
        <td><form:radiobutton path="script" value="2"/></td>
    </tr>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
</form:form>
```

2.Modify you controller to get the submited values.

```
@Controller
// handling methods are relative to this controller
public class ChecklistController {
    private ChecklistService service;
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ChecklistController.class);

    //Called when you submit data and access it like this.
    @RequestMapping("/checklist")
    public ModelAndView checklist(@ModelAttribute(value="UserSel")UserSel userSel) throws Exception{

        //userSel.get..... you will get submited values like this here. Use your service class here. And return appropriate ModelAndView

        return mavChecklist;
    }

    //Call this method first to get blank jsp. This will bind your dataclass to jsp, in which you will get data once you submit.
     @RequestMapping("/newcheklist")
    public ModelAndView viewRender() {
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("UserSel ", new UserSel ());
        mav.setViewName("checklist");
        return mav;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setService(ChecklistService service){
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

*As you didn't provide more code like context files, i need to take certain assumptions*.

Comment: I can provide those if you need to. So I am a bit confused on "/newcheklist". This is binding the dataclass to jsp? Is this a whole new jsp file that will get redirected to?

Comment: /newChecklist will be called first time say from "New" link you clicking. so this viewRender will provide you jsp with commandclass already bind with it. And when you submit you will call "/checklist" url for form processin, ie passing it to service layer for storing. Can you provide your web.xml and ApplicationContext so that i can tell you how exactly you gonna call it?

Comment: web.xml - http://pastebin.com/EVEZuLpQ and spring-servlet.xml - http://pastebin.com/7rbC3EYc  I had to put them in pastebin because of comment word count.

Comment: I have modified both files at pastebin. Have a look at them. Now your spring servlet is bind with url /web/* . So to call your Form hit url like <Weburl upto context>/web/newchecklist (this will show you form. Now give appropriate values and hit submit button. The form's action is like "/web/checklist". so it will hit "checklist method of controller" And here you will get the data.

Comment: I don't see the changes in pastebin

Comment: My mistake i created version but didnt expected its url wil be changed. Its now 1)http://pastebin.com/axRKqnXY 2)http://pastebin.com/ziAPAs0N. web.xml and applicationContext receptively.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not able to view it now after the web.xml change. I would normally get to it from http://localhost:8080/automation-web/ but I get this error, type Status report

message /automation-web/

description The requested resource (/automation-web/) is not available.

Comment: Also, I edited the main post to show what I have for ChecklistController.java, is this the main idea?

Comment: How you calling your controller from JSP? Also from your comments, call like http://localhost:8080/automation-web/web/newchecklist. Assuming "Automation-web" is name of the war/webapplicaiton you creating.

Comment: As looks like you are not aware much about Spring, Found one useful URL for you. Follow this. http://camelcode.org/tutorial/Spring-MVC-3-Form-processing-Annotation-config.htm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13789/discussion-between-rohan-and-david-ellinger)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will allow you to receive the posted form inputs as parameters to your request handler:

```
@RequestMapping("/checklist")
public ModelAndView checklist(
    @RequestParam("FQDN") String FQDN,
    @RequestParam("rdoScript") int rdoScript) {
    // ...
}
```

See the [Spring Framework Reference Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam) for more information.

Comment: I will try this out at work. What is it that I will be returning? Do I declare a new ModelAndView? Also, I very much appreciate your assistance!!!

Comment: I think you can pass ModelAndView as one of the parameters and Spring will supply one.